# int a = (2, 3, 4, 5); & int a = {2, 3, 4, 5}; How these statements are working in C/C++?

Tags: c

I am experimenting with this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = {6};
  printf("%d", a);
  
  return 0;
}
```

It prints 6. Same is the case with below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = (6);
  printf("%d", a);
  
  return 0;
}
```

But how this code is generating the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = (2, 3, 4, 5);  // or {2, 3, 4, 5} in place of parenthesis
  printf("%d", a--);
  printf("%d", --a);
  
  return 0;
}
```

It prints 53. Why it is considering the last value 5 for int variable **a** (when it is enclosed in parenthesis)? Also, why 2 for int variable **a** when it is enclosed in curly braces?

Comment: Enclosed in parentheses, you're getting the comma operator.  Look that up.

Comment: First question: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do).  Second question: [I don't believe that compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/YbcfKEsPf).

Comment: @DrewDormann second code is working with warning in this [platform](https://www.onlinegdb.com/)